# MATLAB roots function different behavior in MATLAB then Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I implemented the following user defined function in MATLAB:

```
function Q = Calc_Q(Head, freq)
b6 = [3.7572E-07 -1.5707E-05 6.0490E-03 5.0018E-02 2.1180E-01];
b5 = [-9.0927E-06 8.9033E-04 -3.2415E-02 5.4525E-01 -8.1649E+00] / 10e2;
b4 = [7.5172E-06 -5.6565E-04 1.0024E-02 3.5888E-01 3.8894E-02] / 10e5;
b3 = [-4.8767E-06 4.8787E-04 -1.3311E-02 -1.2189E-01 -5.3522E+00] / 10e8;
b2 = [5.9227E-06 -8.1716E-04 3.5392E-02 -4.5413E-01 1.9547E+00] / 10e11;
b1 = [-2.0004E-06 2.9027E-04 -1.3754E-02 2.3490E-01 -1.2363E+00] / 10e14;

a = [polyval(b1,abs(freq)), polyval(b2, abs(freq)), polyval(b3, abs(freq)), polyval(b4, abs(freq)), polyval(b5, abs(freq)), polyval(b6, abs(freq)) - Head];

Q_roots = roots(a);
%Delete roots with imaginary part
i = 1;
while i <= length(Q_roots)
    if(imag(Q_roots(i)) ~= 0)
        Q_roots(i) = [];
        i = i - 1;
    end
    i = i + 1;
end
%Delete roots with real part greater then 3100
i = 1;
while i <= length(Q_roots)
    if(Q_roots(i) >= 3100 || Q_roots(i) < 0)
        Q_roots(i) = [];
        i = i - 1;
    end
    i = i +1;
end

if freq < 0
    Q = real(Q_roots(1)) * -1;
else
    Q = real(Q_roots(1));        
end
end
```

When I Call this function in Matlab it works fine. However if I use this exact code as a MATLAB function in simulink it stop's working. (actually it works, but the ouput is always zero.)

I do have a suspicion of what the problem might be. When running the script in de-bugging mode, I cannot view a result for Q_roots (It just doesn't display anything).

```
Q_roots = roots(a);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Which Simulink block did you use to call this function? Are the inputs to the function ok in Simulink?

Comment: I used the "MATLAB function" block...
My guess is the inputs are ok... I just wired 2 constants to the inputs

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely due to your logic that eliminates any roots that do not have *exactly* zero in the imaginary part.  This is a mathematical way of thinking that does not really work well numerically, at least not in general.  All the roots are probably being found in both cases (there is no limitation that implies otherwise), but in Simulink and in code generation the problem is treated as a complex one, and some roots might be coming back with tiny imaginary parts.  Instead of deleting roots if their imaginary parts are not exactly zero, eliminate the roots with imaginary parts that are numerically *insignificant*, either very small *relative* to the real part or very small altogether.  Something like

```
tol = 10*eps(class(Q_roots));
keepers = abs(imag(Q_roots)) < tol*max(abs(real(Q_roots)),1) & ...
    real(Q_roots) >= 0 & real(Q_roots) <= 3100;
Q_roots = Q_roots(keepers);
```

would take care of all the deletions in one fell swoop.  I used 10*eps as a tolerance here.

But if you only need the first qualifying root, then you could just do this:

```
Q = nan('like',a);
tol = 10*eps(class(a));
for k = 1:numel(Q_roots)
    r = real(Q_roots(k));
    if abs(imag(Q_roots(k))) < tol*max(abs(r),1) && r >= 0 && r <= 3100;
        Q = r;
        break
    end
end

if freq < 0
    Q = -Q;
end
```

Comment: Michael, If I look at the roots that the function roots() is producing respectively in Matlab and simulink, Simulink does produce a different result (i.e less found roots, and not the one's I am interested in.)

Comment: Could you provide me with exact Head and Freq inputs that demonstrates this?  We expect numerically minor differences and different ordering.  We do *not* expect "less roots" or "different ones" except in case of extreme ill-conditioning, in which case one or the other might give more pleasing results but not consistently. The principal advantage MATLAB has in the matter is being able to use an eigenvalue solver for a real matrix, which will result in exact complex conjugate pairs for the non-real roots.

Answer (score 2):

Oke I found the problem.

From a different forum:

> Hi Cosmin,
>
> I took a look at the implementation of roots for the Embedded MATLAB
>   Function block (\toolbox\eml\lib\matlab\polyfun\roots.m).
>   It's stated there:
>
> %   Limitations: %     Output is always variable size. %     Output is
>   always complex. %     Roots may not be in the same order as MATLAB. % 
>   Roots of poorly conditioned polynomials may not match MATLAB. The last
>   sentence is what makes you the headache (and yes, your polynomial is
>   badly conditioned!). If you take a look at the plot you will see, that
>   the curve hardly touches the x-axis.
>
> I have a suggestion though: the value -z/b is a (very) good
>   approximation of the root you are looking for ...?
>
> Titus

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25624-roots-in-simulink

Apparently the root function in simulink does not always found all the roots of a given polynominal.
This is unfortunate and not easily solvable. I did however found a solution.

For all the different polynomials I have to solve, I know the interval of the root I am interested in ( [-3000, 3000]).

I just basically takes steps of 50 from -3000 to 3000, until the function drops below 0. I then know the approximate solution of the root. I use this approximation as seed for the Newton-Raphson method.

Straight implementation of the Newton raphson method with a given seed for all the polynomials I have to solve did not work because sometimes it iterated to a different root (one which i was not interested in.)

Here's the code:

```
function Q = Calc_Q(Head, freq)
    b6 = [3.7572E-07 -1.5707E-05 6.0490E-03 5.0018E-02 2.1180E-01];
    b5 = [-9.0927E-06 8.9033E-04 -3.2415E-02 5.4525E-01 -8.1649E+00] / 10e2;
    b4 = [7.5172E-06 -5.6565E-04 1.0024E-02 3.5888E-01 3.8894E-02] / 10e5;
    b3 = [-4.8767E-06 4.8787E-04 -1.3311E-02 -1.2189E-01 -5.3522E+00] / 10e8;
    b2 = [5.9227E-06 -8.1716E-04 3.5392E-02 -4.5413E-01 1.9547E+00] / 10e11;
    b1 = [-2.0004E-06 2.9027E-04 -1.3754E-02 2.3490E-01 -1.2363E+00] / 10e14;

    %coeff for the polynominal
    a = [polyval(b1,abs(freq)), polyval(b2, abs(freq)), polyval(b3, abs(freq)), polyval(b4, abs(freq)), polyval(b5, abs(freq)), polyval(b6, abs(freq)) - Head];

    %coeff for the derrivative of polynominal
    da = [5*a(1) 4*a(2) 3*a(3) 2*a(4) a(5)];

    Q = -3000;
    %Search for point where function goes below 0
    while (polyval(a, Q) > 0)
        Q = Q + 25;
    end    
    error_max = 0.01
    iter_counter = 1;
    while abs(polyval(a,Q)) >= error_max && iter_counter <= 1000
        Q = Q - polyval(a, Q)/polyval(da, Q);
        iter_counter = iter_counter + 1;
        error = abs(polyval(a,Q));
    end
    if(freq < 0)
        Q = Q * - 1;
    end
end
```